# How to display logger for Start time and End time automatically in Spring Boot using Annotations

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to log the start time and end time for methods in Spring boot using annotations and without using any logger object (Eg. Log.Info). Is there any way of doing it automatically using annotations.

Comment: Expecting an alternative way to do it other than **Spring AOP**. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, it can be achieved automatically using annotations. Best approach is profiling the methods using **Spring AOP**.

Have a look at this [blog](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/01/spring-aop-example-profiling-method-execution-time-tutorial/)

Comment: I was expecting Spring Boot to have some configurations in the application.properties and achieve it using annotations like **@Transactional**

Comment: I said already. Just FYI all spring boot properties you can find here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html